Uploading new release to Google play internal testing track when app is in draft mode
I created a new app in Google play and it is still in draft mode, i.e. not all privacy policies, screen shots etc have been setup yet.
In internal testing track I have manually uploaded a version of the app and it is working properly. I can also create a new release by manually uploading the aab file and when I click Save and Publish it will replace the old release.
Now I'm trying to upload a new version from my release pipeline. Everything is working except publishing and replacing the old release. The api will only create the release if its status is draft, which will keep the old release in completed state. If I set the new release to completed state I get error

Only releases with status draft may be created on draft app.

When I query the api for all releases I get this back, where one release in is completed state.
{
  "track": "internal",
  "releases": [
    {
      "name": "1.7.9003",
      "versionCodes": [
        "9003"
      ],
      "status": "draft"
    },
    {
      "name": "8008 (1.7.8008)",
      "versionCodes": [
        "8008"
      ],
      "status": "completed"
    }
  ]
}

So that should indicate than a release can be and should be in completed state.
When I go into the web ui I see the draft release and I can open it and click Save and Publish and it will replace the old release.
What commands is the web ui using to accomplish this?
